# Pagination - page numbering

Tags: page-numbering

My document class is: Article (Standard Class with more sizes and fonts).
My goal was to number the pages, where the first one with roman pagination (i, ii, ...) and the rest with arabic pagination (1,2,...).
I've tried writing on the LaTex preamble: `\pagenumbering{roman}`

and then, where i want to switch back (somewhere on the page in the normal text), in ERT (Ctrl-L):

`\pagenumbering{arabic}`

`\setcounter{page}{1}`

but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE...

If you are using standard `book.cls` file instead of `article`, then the tags `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` will take care of the page numbering styles by auto, and the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
Test
\mainmatter
Test
\backmatter
Test
\end{document}
```

If you want to use the `article`, then the tag is:

`\pagenumbering{roman}`

Comment: It's not working  ://